# Applications of Schubert calculus

Tags: co.combinatorics, complex-geometry, grassmannians, homogeneous-spaces, schubert-calculus

[Schubert calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schubert_calculus) is a venerable field in mathematics where the object of study is the cohomology ring of the Grassmannians. Since it has been around for over a hundred years one might wonder if any real world applications in physics for example have been found.

> **QUESTIONS.**
>
> (a) Does anybody know of such applications?
>
> (b) Moreover, have applications to other areas of mathematics been found?

Comment: I think the use of Schubert calculus to resolve Horn's conjecture (which describes what eigenvalues $A+B$ can have when $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices with prescribed sets of eigenvalues) is quite impressive; see the survey article: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0009048

Comment: Actually, this survey describes in much more detail the relevant Schubert calculus: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908012

Comment: As for applications of Schubert calculus to physics, I would suggest you look at the positive Grassmannian/the "amplituhedron"; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5605 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2007

Comment: Applications to quantum information theory are described in [Quantum State Transformations and the Schubert Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0410052)

Comment: Another application of the positive Grassmannian is the work of Kodama and Williams on KP solitons. Their main paper is https://math.berkeley.edu/~williams/papers/KW-ArxivVersion.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

[This survey paper survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0410052v1.pdf) illustrates some particular applications to quantum
information theory.

Another interplay with the six-vertex model in physics can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4718), for instance.

Comment: I must have been typing while you posted. :-)

Comment: Here is another survey by Allen Knutson on Schubert Calculus and Quantum Information: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~allenk/qclectures.pdf. More precisely, it is related to a problem called "Quantum Marginal Problem", which asks about the conditions on compatibility of reduced density matrices of sub-systems and global density matrix of a composite finite-dimensional quantum system. For more details, please see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0409113v1.pdf